# Oracle SQL adding multi-line table comment or column comment

Tags: sql, oracle, multiline, comments

I want to add multi-line table/column comment.

Normally this is used;

```
COMMENT ON TABLE USERS IS 'User table has the user data'
```

What I need is a way to insert the new-line inside the single quotation marks like;

```
COMMENT ON TABLE USERS IS 'User table has the user data <smthg_here_for_new_line> 1- Name column has name <smthg_here_for_new_line> 2- Number Column has the id'
```

So that table comments will be seen like;

```
User table has the user data
1- Name column has name
2- Number Column has the id
```

Anybody knows how add multi-line table/column comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply put line feeds inside the single-quotes of your comment declaration, for example:

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN MYTABLE.MYCOLUMN
IS
'Line 1
Line 2.
Line 3';
```

Note, however, that in SQL Developer (and perhaps other tools) this will not *always* display as expected. With the following query ...

```
SELECT *
FROM USER_COL_COMMENTS
WHERE
  TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE'
  AND COMMENTS IS NOT NULL;
```

... you'll get exactly what you're looking for in Script Output (i.e., highlight the query, right-click, select "Run Script"):

```
TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME COMMENTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
---------- ----------- --------------
MYTABLE    MYCOLUMN    Line 1
                       Line 2
                       Line 3
MYTABLE    OTHERCOLUMN Other comments
```

But in a Query Result (i.e., highlight the query, right-click, select "Run Statement"), or when opening the table and looking at the Columns tab, the full comment will be run together on a single line.

Note: The tables in which these comments can be queried are:

- Comments on tables: `USER_TAB_COMMENTS`
- Comments on columns: `USER_COL_COMMENTS`

Answer (score 0):

In SQLPlus you can use concat with chr(10) (or chr(13) || chr(10) in Microsoft Windows environment):

```
'User table has the user data' || chr(10) || '1- Name column has name...'
```

Also, it should be possible to just interpret newlines by setting SQLBLANKLINES to ON:

```
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON
COMMENT ON TABLE USERS IS 'User table has the user data
1- Name column has name
2- Number Column has the id'
```

Comment: I tried that and get the error below. I ran it on TOAD as a single SQL statement, the error is as below;

    COMMENT ON TABLE USER IS 'User table comment1 here' || chr(10) || '1- User table subcomment here'
    Error at line 1
    ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: And neither chr(10) nor chr(13) worked (at first I tried chr(10) because the oracle server is on the *nix machine, then I tried chr(13) because I try it via TOAD software, which is running on a windows machine but none worked)